# How do I prevent wordpress plugin assets (css and js files) to load on all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress slider plugin called - Master Slider (https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider), which I am using on the home page of this site - http://lanarratrice-al-rawiya.com/lanarratrice

Even if the slider is used on home page, the css and js files that come with slider are being loaded on all the pages, and increasing the number of http requests. How can I make the slider css and js  files to load only on the home page?

I tried using the following code snippet in functions.php file, as described in this link- (http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/08/06/how-to-disable-scripts-and-styles) but no luck.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
    if (!(is_front_page()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-easing' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'masterslider-core' );
    }
}
```

In the Master Slider admin section, there is an advanced setting to prevent the js and css from loading on all the pages as shown in the picture attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an error in your code, you missed to close if condition with `)`:

```
if (!(is_front_page()) {
```

Should be

```
if ( !( is_front_page() ) ) { 
OR
if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
```

This is how you can get all the enqueued css and scripts:

```
global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;
//var_dump( $wp_scripts );
//var_dump( $wp_styles );
```

Comment: Thank you Jogesh for your prompt response and pointing out my mistake.  Correcting the mistake above fixes the issue of javascript being loaded on all the pages. Now javascript is loading only on the home page which is the desired behaviour.  The problem is - css for this slider is still loading on all pages. How can I prevent the css to load on all the pages. Thanks.

Comment: @Vik `wp_deregister_style()` take a look on the link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style

Comment: I am already using the wp_deregister_style() to remove the styles applied by contact form 7 plugin on all the pages. And it works fine. I am just adding the style handle in the function like this: wp_deregister_script( 'contact-form-7' ); In this case the name of the handle is - "contact-form-7". I found this handle by going through the plugin file, and looking for wp_enqueue_style() functions. But I cannot find the style handle for  Master Slider plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider). Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try with `global $wp_styles` or with `global $wp_scripts` that gives you all list of enqued css and scripts then detect the exact handle and deregister it.